# Passing value from labelbox to a linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Hello guys i am new to linq and so is in .net. i want pass a value from label box to a linq query as parameter.below is the code ...

```
namespace PblCard.PublicWeb
{
public partial class Cardno : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Page.User.IsInRole(SecurityEngine.Roles.Customer))
                {
                    Customer customer = new      CustomerEngine().GetCustomerByEmail(Page.User.Identity.Name);

                    if (customer == null)
                        throw new ApplicationException(Properties.Resources.CustomerNotFound);



                    lblCardNo.Text = customer.CardNumber;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ASPxButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string panno = lblCardNo.Text;

        using (Entities query = new Entities())
        {
            var txn = from p in query.TRANSACTIONs
                      .Where(x => x.PAN == panno)
                      select p;
            GridView1.DataSource = txn;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }
}
}
```

but when binding to grid i am not getting any output. but if i use this

```
protected void ASPxButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string panno = lblCardNo.Text;

        using (Entities query = new Entities())
        {
            var txn = from p in query.TRANSACTIONs
                      .Where(x => x.PAN == ("234567"))
                      select p;
            GridView1.DataSource = txn;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

    }
}
```

the grid is showing data. How should I write the query?

Comment: If you step through your click event, can you see the value you expected in the string?

Answer (score 1):

Databinding does not work with raw LINQ queries.

You need to write `GridView1.DataSource = txn.ToList();`

Comment: SLaks thanks for ur comment .......yes i have tried both Tolist and ToArray....... but still no luck ......

Answer (score 0):

Add break point on panno to check if there is value pass  from lblCardNo.Text.

```
string panno = lblCardNo.Text;         <-- here

var txn = (from p in query.TRANSACTIONs
          where Convert.ToString(p.PAN.ToString) == Convert.ToString(panno)    <-- here
          select p).ToList();

            GridView1.DataSource = txn;
            GridView1.DataBind();

then try to point to txn and check' results view' if it has a data.
```

Regards

Comment: yes i have check that at beginning ......yes the values are going ..... to me it seems  that lblCardNo.Text has the data type NVARCHAR2

Comment: and the p.pan has the data type char. Is there any chance that data type is mismatched in the linq query?!!! now i am really pissed off

Comment: i have edited my post. what it do is to convert pan and panno to string so it have the same datatype.

Comment: 'code'   protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string panno = lblCardNo.Text;

            using (Entities query = new Entities())
            {
                var txn = (from p in query.TRANSACTIONs
                           where Convert.ToString(p.PAN) == Convert.ToString(panno)
                           select p).ToList();

                GridView1.DataSource = txn;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Source Error: 


Line 56:             string panno = lblCardNo.Text;
Line 57: 
Line 58:             using (Entities query = new Entities())
Line 59:             {
Line 60:                 var txn = (from p in query.TRANSACTIONs

Comment: _italic_  Entity Framework 4 Limitation - [System.NotSupportedException] - "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Comment: <pre> protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pan = Convert.ToString(lblCardNo.Text);
            

            using (Entities query = new Entities())
            {
                var txn = (from p in query.TRANSACTIONs
                           where p.PAN.Contains(pan)
                           select p).ToList();

                GridView1.DataSource = txn;
                GridView1.DataBind();

            }<code>